# Appending a DataFrame in a nested for loop without appending NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, nan

I have a nested for loop that iterates through a dictionary and pulls out specific slices of data and appends the slice into a new dictionary. I am not sure if this has something to do with the index on append or the amount of loops or neither. The code is shown below.

```
def combine_timesteps(channels, startpoint = 5):
    startpoint_start = startpoint
    endpoint = None
    
    timestep_dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Discharge': discharge_values_at_strain_times[startpoint:endpoint]}).transpose()

    for channel in channels.items():
        
        for i, time_data in enumerate(channel[1]):
                        
            data = channel[1][startpoint:endpoint]
            time_int_string = str(channel[0]) + ' t-' + str(i)
            df_to_append = pd.DataFrame({time_int_string:data})

            timestep_dataset = timestep_dataset.append(df_to_append[time_int_string])
            
            print(timestep_dataset)
            
            new_start = startpoint - 1
            startpoint = new_start
            
            if endpoint == None:
                endpoint = 0
            new_end = endpoint - 1
            endpoint = new_end
            
            if startpoint == -1: 
                startpoint = startpoint_start
                endpoint = None
                break
    
    timestep_dataset_formatted = timestep_dataset.transpose()      
    
    return timestep_dataset_formatted
```

However, whenever a new append happens, it slides the data that is appended down with amount NaN values equal to the startpoint integer in front as shown below.

```
Discharge           9.913190    9.908002    9.902636    9.897269    9.891902   
Channel 750 t-0          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
Channel 750 t-1          NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  259.839939   
Channel 750 t-2          NaN         NaN         NaN  274.439453  259.839939   
Channel 750 t-3          NaN         NaN  269.095527  274.439453  259.839939   
Channel 750 t-4          NaN  363.006610  269.095527  274.439453  259.839939   
Channel 750 t-5   977.719896  363.006610  269.095527  274.439453  259.839939   
Channel 1300 t-0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
Channel 1300 t-1         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  325.599363   
Channel 1300 t-2         NaN         NaN         NaN  420.957686  325.599363   
Channel 1300 t-3         NaN         NaN  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363   
Channel 1300 t-4         NaN  444.503183  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363   
Channel 1300 t-5  964.735686  444.503183  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363
```

The desired output format is for the first value in the t-0 column to be the first non NaN value (basically sliding each column up spaces until there isn't a NaN value) and so on. I am unsure why the dataframe that is grabbed first and appended has the NaN values out front.

```
Discharge           9.913190    9.908002    9.902636    9.897269    9.891902   
Channel 750 t-0   287.678547  264.190236  182.871974  208.402388  246.174055
Channel 750 t-1   259.839939  287.678547  264.190236  182.871974  208.402388 
Channel 750 t-2   274.439453  259.839939  287.678547  264.190236  182.871974 
Channel 750 t-3   269.095527  274.439453  259.839939  287.678547  264.190236 
Channel 750 t-4   363.006610  269.095527  274.439453  259.839939  287.678547
Channel 750 t-5   977.719896  363.006610  269.095527  274.439453  259.839939   
Channel 1300 t-0  362.181147  403.321962  423.858839  341.982210  237.443283   
Channel 1300 t-1  325.599363  362.181147  403.321962  423.858839  341.982210 
Channel 1300 t-2  420.957686  325.599363  362.181147  403.321962  423.858839 
Channel 1300 t-3  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363  362.181147  403.321962 
Channel 1300 t-4  444.503183  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363  362.181147 
Channel 1300 t-5  964.735686  444.503183  376.701738  420.957686  325.599363
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. I had to make sure to reset the index on each loop. I can do that by using the .reset_index(drop = True) method such that the new line reads . . .

```
df_to_append = pd.DataFrame({time_int_string:data}).reset_index(drop = True)
```

This will ensure that the data is appended in the correct location.